# Bitbucket branch management

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

Is this possible with **BitBucket** or **GitHub** to restrict the user for any particular branch except "master"? I only want to share "master" branch with others and develop branch should be keep private with me and my developers. So no one can even "checkout" develop branch if permission is not given.

Any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict in "writing" access (push) with [BitBucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) or [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/), or with a git server using **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#overview)**.

But you cannot restrict in "reading" access: if you can clone part of a repo, you can clone the all repo.

> develop branch should be keep private with me and my developers.

That means having those branch in a *separate* repo: you can restrict the visibility of a all repo (for instance: a private repo with BitBucket)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know how to restrict "write" access. My only concern is about reading access. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: Please update this if you get to know any possibility in future.

Comment: @Muzammil Sure, but in the meantime, this answer stands.